# Laravel union order by a new field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a local scope `scopeSearch` which takes a string, explode it by some delimiter, and now i want to have the records matching those words, and the code looks like this:

```
public function scopeSearch($query,string $keywords){
    $str = str_replace('.', '%', $keywords);
    $str = str_replace(',', '%', $str);
    $str = str_replace(' ', '%', $str);
    foreach (self::FIELDS_TO_SEARCH as $field)
        $where[] = [$field, 'like', $str];
}
```

but now i want to have first the results with a match the original string, and then those which match with this new string `str`, so i've done this:

```
public function scopeSearch($query,string $keywords){
    $query2 = clone $query;
    $str = str_replace('.', '%', $keywords);
    $str = str_replace(',', '%', $str);
    $str = str_replace(' ', '%', $str);
    foreach (self::FIELDS_TO_SEARCH as $field){
        $query->orWhere($field, 'like', "%$str%");
        $query2->orWhere($field, 'like', "%$keywords%");
    }
    $query2->union($query);
    return $query;
}
```

But `MySQL union` as far as i know, does not guarantee order, and so i would like to add a field to the two query, where in the first one is like `select 1 as rank` and in the second one is `select 2 as rank`, and than `orderBy('rank')`... is there some way to do it?